# Crashlytics logs in ios framework

Tags: ios, crashlytics

In `Crashltyics` dashboard, I could see some logs frequently in `iOS` frameworks like `CoreFoundation`, `CFNetwork`, `WebCore`, `AVFoundation` and in our code also. 
We never come across this crashes in our testing, in production, it is happening. I want to know, users really face this problem (app kill) for all these logs or only logs are being posted.

Comment: How can you be sure that your app didn't crash in production ?

Answer (score 1):

We have to face the same problem to over come it. we have to create the local logs (with title debug or info) to publish on crashlytics. Now when we receive the crash we have to follow the logs flow to reach that problem. for example logs of an error

user login successfully
user upload the picture
picture upload api failed/ or received wrong mime-type on server etc

these local logs would generate on send and receive api requests